# apple web backend technology

Tags: javascript, backend

As you know apple use javascript/sproutcore for its products as mobileme.com and iwork.com. what did they use as backend? javascript server-side?

Answer (score 5):

"PHP, MySQL, Ruby on Rails, JavaScript, CSS"

Based on this job posting: 
http://jobs.apple.com/index.ajs?BID=1&method=mExternal.showJob&RID=49462

Comment: I interviewed wtih Apple, and they used PHP and MySQL, but it was for an internal website.